# CanCan issues with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I am having a issue with an owner on my rails application not being able to access my Map controller create and show methods using the CanCanCan gem for permissions control.

Here is my ability model with the current config:

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)

 if user.role.name == 'owner'

   can :manage, Map, venue_id: user.company.venues.pluck(:id)

 end
end
```

Output from user.company.venues.pluck(:id):

```
 Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT `venues`.`id` FROM `venues` WHERE `venues`.`company_id` = 4
 => [1]
```

Here is my Maps Controller Code:

```
class MapsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :html, :json
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    respond_with(@maps)
  end

  def new
   respond_with(@maps)
  end

  def create
    @map = Map.create(map_params)
    if @map.save
      respond_to do |format|
        flash[:notice] = t('floors.created')
        format.json
      end
    else
      flash[:alert] = t('floors.error')
    end
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@map)
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update

  end

  def map_params
    params.require(:map).permit(:alias, :venue_id, :map)
  end

end
```

Maps belong to venues and has a venue_id. I can get Maps in the Maps index partial on my venue page:
[image: Venue Maps]

But when I try to create a Map or go to the Map show page I get a CanCan access denied error:
[image: CanCan Access Denied]

Any ideas on why CanCanCan would allow me to view the Maps index but get access denied when creating or viewing the Map show controller.

Comment: Don't use images, paste code into SO instead. Also, include controller code as well as ability file code. Why did you have to show us your UI, what does that have to do with anything? Lastly, with the user used, what's the output of `current_user.company.venues.pluck(:id)`?

Comment: The output is the venue id which is 1:   

Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT `venues`.`id` FROM `venues` WHERE `venues`.`company_id` = 4
 => [1]

Comment: Using console, what's the `venue_id` for the map you were trying to `show`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure about you're `#show` action, but definitely shouldn't have:

```
can :manage, Map, venue_id: condition
```

The reason being that your resource `@map = Map.new` will not have a venue yet.

It's going to check:

```
@map.venue_id
=> nil
current_user.company.venues.pluck(:id)
=> [1]
@map.venue_id ==  current_user.company.venues.pluck(:id)
# aka     nil == [1]
=> false
```

Try the following:

```
can [:new, :create], Map
can [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy], Map, venue_id: condition
```

Comment: Thank you, this definitely solved the issue with creating a Map.

Comment: For the #show issue, I had the venue_id for Maps as a string instead of an integer as the venue.id is. :facepalm: Thanks again for the assist!

Comment: Lol all good! Thanks for taking the time to specify your issue with `#show`. It's really important for people discovering `cancancan` who might stubble across the same misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly stating the class in the load_and_authorize_resource

`load_and_authorize_resource class: "Map"`